# Seaburn dataset shows a different output as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I'm watching some data science education videos and I am studing list dict comprehensions. As you can see at the first pic, the teacher just executed that `df.columns` part and the output has shown at the console but when I tried the same thing console didn't show to me directly as I did the same things as the video. Why I can't see the result of `df.columns` as in video?

First pic from video.education
[image]

The second pic from my work [image]

Answer (score 0):

The pictures doesn't show the same code.

if you want to see the same output, try:

```py
df.columns = [col.lower() for col in df.columns]
df.columns
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Or did you need some further assistance?